# How can I use a specific version of ink?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, rust

I want to use a specific version of ink!, version 3.0.0-rc7 for example. How can I define that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set a fixed dependency version in your `Cargo.toml` by using `=` in front of the version number. For example, like this:

```
ink_primitives = { version = "=3.0.0-rc9", default-features = false }
```

So you would just have to prefix all ink! `version` entries in your `Cargo.toml` with a `=`.

Due to the nature of semantic versioning (https://semver.org/) the newest release candidate is always fetched automatically, so you have to pin the explicit version if you want to keep a certain one.